# Connectivity between datanodes

Tags: hadoop

Is it possible to have datanode which does not have interconnectivity. but all datanode can talk to the namenode.

For eg: I have 4 slaves, 2 local vm in my machine and 2 network vm's and my machine is the master. Network VM cant ping my local vm. is this condition valid in hadoop configuration. Is it possible to make sure if data goes to network vm, it should only be replicated between the network vm .

Answer (score 0):

In reduce phase required intemediate data from peer nodes through http are collected. A certain communication between the nodes is that's why required. If it cannot for an instance, there might be errors.